# C# linq query filter child Collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-5

Good day,

I have a model class like below

```
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
      [Key]
     public int employeeId{get;set;}
     public string Fullname {get;set;}
     public string Address{get;set;}
     public ICollection<PaymentModel> Payments {get;set;}
    }


    public class PaymentModel
    {

      [Key]
     public int PaymentId{get; set;}
     public int employeeId{get; set;}
     public decimal PaymentAmount{get; set;}
      public int IsPosted {get; set;}
      public virtual EmployeeModel Employee {get; set;}

    }
```

i just want to query the list of employee together with their list of payments using linq. so i code like this:

```
dbcontext db = new dbcontext();
var listing = from d in db.Employees
              .include("Payments")
               select d;
```

this listing show the all of the employee and all its payments.
but i need to filter each employee Payments that IsPosted = 1

so as initial answer, ill do this code;

```
dbcontext db = new dbcontext();
List<EmployeeModel> FinalList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
var listingofEmp = db.employee.ToList();

foreach(EmployeeModel emp in listingofEmp){
emp.Payments= db.payments.where(x => x.IsPosted == 1).ToList();
FinalList.Add(emp);
}
```

my Question is, is ther any other way to code it much easier? something like this.

```
    dbcontext db = new dbcontext();
    var listing = from d in db.Employees
                  .include(d => x.Payments.IsPosted == 1)
                   select d;
```

im curently using entityframework 5

ive research regarding it not work for me [Link](https://www.google.com.ph/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=how%20to%20filter%20child%20collections%20in%20linq&oq=how%20to%20filter%20child%20collec&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0j69i60l2.8926j0j7)

Hope someone will help me

Thanks In Advance Guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What are you asking for is not natively supported, so there is no easier way, but for sure there is more efficient way because your current code is performing N + 1 database queries.

A better way could be to retrieve employees and related filtered payments with one database query using anonymous type projection, and then do something similar to your approach to create the final result in memory. For instance:

```
var listing = 
    db.Employees.Select(employee => new
    {
        employee,
        payments = employee.Payments.Where(p => p.IsPosted == 1)
    })
    .AsEnumerable() // Switch to LINQ to Objects
    .Select(r =>
    {
        r.employee.Payments = r.payments.ToList();
        return r.employee;
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It works like a charm.. !!! Thanks for Helping sir Ivan.. Sir ivan can i ask where i can learn more in linq? any links or books? hope to hear from you sir PLEASE ;(...

Comment: Hi Neil, I really don't know what to suggest you. I'm sure there are a lot good books/links for LINQ, but I personally learned everything from MSDN topics and mainly experimenting. Note that different LINQ implementations have specifics, so for instance the above may or may not apply to the newest EF Core.

Comment: Is there an equivalent way of doing this using linq in ef6?  I tried the same logic in ef6 but it is not filtering the child collection.

Comment: @overloading It should work in EF6. Just make sure the collection navigation property is not `virtual`, or lazy loading is disabled, because the lazy loading will override the filtering.

Comment: @IvanStoev, that worked beautifully! In the first Select, it's filtering the payments and creating a var for it. In the second Select, it's setting the list on the parent from that filtered list. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

it colud be a good alternative

```
var listing = from d in db.Payments
              .include("Employees")
              .where d.IsPosted == 1
               select d.Employees;
```

(not tested, then please fix mistakes)

start from pyaments, filter for is posted=1
, then select related emplyees

Comment: thanks for immediate Answere @Danilo Calzetta.. i will try with this :D

Comment: Hi sir @Danilo Calzetta, is there another way? i need to bind the list of Employee then the subreport  of its Payments.. this way will be more hard cause i need to loop Each Payment to group to a single list.. so i can bind it to List view of my WPF UI..

Comment: @Neil please look at my example query, it returns exactly a list di employees, becouse selects "d.emplyees" and not "d"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: It will give you a list of anonymous type that will hold the employee and it's payments.

```
using (dbcontext ctx = new dbcontext())
{
    ctx.Connection.Open();

    var result = (from e in ctx.Employees
                  join p in ctx.Payments on e.employeeId equals p.employeeId
                  where p.IsPosted == 1
                  select new
                  {
                      Employee = e,
                      Payments = p
                  }).ToList();

    ctx.Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: hi @Paul how can i used the result?? i want to encapsulate it into List of employee  so i can bind it to my WPF UI..sorry for noob question